# CiviCRM seems to block PUT requests to Gravity Forms API

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to write a simple script that updates entries in `Gravity Forms` via their REST API.  `GET` requests to the API work successfully, but `POST`s and `PUT`s (I have not tried `DELETE`) do not appear to be routed correctly.

Instead, I am getting what appears to be a `CiviCRM` error template, but not wrapped by the rest of the site HTML. (See below)

Disabling `CiviCRM` in `wordpress` gets my script working as designed.

I am running `CiviCRM` version 4.7 and `Gravity Forms` version 2.1.0.1

```
<div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @import url(/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css);
    @import url(/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
  </style>
    <div class="messages status no-popup">
        <i class="crm-i fa-exclamation-triangle crm-i-red"></i>
        <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span>
        <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Error type: Could not find a valid session key.</div>
        <p>
            <a href="https://www.lofcenter.org/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle( element ) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var className = parent.className;
    if ( className  == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') {
        parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper  crm-fatal-error-details-block';
    } else {
        parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block';
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there a configuration change that I need to make?  Or is there some kind of known workaround?

Comment: There is a CoTS integration between CiviCRM and Gravity Forms (https://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/). Maybe this fits your business case.

Comment: I am not looking for integration, I am simply trying to PUT data to the gravity forms API, but CiviCRM is intercepting the route.  Disabling the CiviCRM plugin fixes the issue, but I need it in production so that's a non-starter.